# Fastest way to count a collection whilst applying criteria

Tags: .net, collections, dictionary, count

I have a dictionary that i have already loaded form the database which contains a customer oject key and a Status value which is an Enum. What I would like to do is to count all the items in the dictionary which have a status of a certain enum type ie "Sent". What would be the best way to go about this without going back to the database, or do i have to go back to the database? I dont really want to loop round the whole collection. I cant use linq as im currently using .Net 2.0

```
public Dictionary<Customer, Status> DistributionList
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to either write a loop or use LINQ. Keep in mind that writing a loop is going to be the fastest method anyway -- certainly faster than querying the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a count of elements in the dictionary with the specific value, you can't avoid looping though the list:

```
int count = 0;
foreach(KeyValuePair<Customer,Status> kvp in DistributionList) {
    if(kvp.Value == Status.Sent) count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a lambda function? e.g.:

```
using System.Linq;

int sentCount = DistributionList.Values.Count(s => s.Status == sent);
```

Comment: Hi Jon, cant use linq as stated in my question.

Comment: Oops fair point! In that case I'd probably simplify the answer from fencliff a bif by looping through DistributionList.Values as these are Statuses, rather than looping on the KVPs.